# Silverstripe 4 LoginForm redirect default_login_dest

Tags: authentication, redirect, yaml, config, silverstripe

I've created a new page type called LoginPage.php. I'm using $LoginForm in the LoginPage template. I want users to be redirected to another page (HomePage.php) depending on what permissions group they are in. By default, if the user is not an administrator there is no redirect and it just reloads the current URL the user is on (LoginPage.php). I want the user to be redirected to HomePage.php.

I've tried using

```
Silverstripe\Security:
  - default_login_dest: '/home'
```

But it has no effect. Maybe I'm using it wrong. Could someone please give clarify how to do this.